# Should I add *internal* properties to the prototype?

Tags: javascript

I know that a consequence of using the prototype is that all added properties and methods will be public. This is not really too much of a problem since I'm using a naming convention to distinguish between the internals vs. the public interface. So yes, everything is still *technically* public.

Would it be best to just add *all* methods and properties to the prototype -- even ones that are intended to be internal -- opposed to only adding *public* methods/properties to the prototype and dynamically creating the internal properties inside the constructor using `this.property = value`.?

It seems that since everything is going to be public anyway, we might as well add internal properties to the prototype as well.

**I know about using closures to create private scope. My question is not about how to create truly private properties (which would mean ditching the prototype as any of those methods would not have internal access privileges), but about best practice when using the prototype.**

```
function MyObjectA() {
   this.myInternalProp_ = 5;
   // ...
}

MyObjectA.prototype.myPublicProp = "Hello";
```

vs.

```
function MyObjectA() {
   // ...
}

MyObjectA.prototype.myPublicProp = "Hello";
MyObjectA.prototype.myInternalProp_ = 5;
```

Comment: Could you provide a code example?

Comment: I don't see what the question is. Are you just asking whether you should use the language constructs available for the purpose of information hiding, or if you shouldn't?

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen The question is this. Should we avoid dynamically creating new properties in the constructor function. Should I instead just put everything on the prototype. This way properties are not being dynamically created; that is, after the prototype has been molded. For example, doing `this.myNewProp = value` trips up the engines' model of my object, and it has to rebuild it's hidden class. That is not my main concern as much as I'm curious about what people think about on a consistency, maintenance perspective.

Comment: FYI, I was a little confused when I asked this question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing properties on the prototype means that the properties are not only public, but *shared*.  This becomes a problem when your property is a mutable type, such as a `Date`:

```
function MyObjectA () { }  
MyObjectA.prototype.date = new Date(2011, 10, 18);
var obj1 = new MyObjectA();
var obj2 = new MyObjectA();
obj1.date.setDate(24);
console.log(obj2.date);  // Thanksgiving, not today
```

See also [Using "prototype" for variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822838/using-prototype-for-variables)

Comment: Thanks; but isn't it only the initial value that is shared. When creating a new instance of an object, all properties on the prototype are cloned; so when I set a property that came from the prototype on one instance, it won't affect the other instances, unless I'm setting on the actual prototype object.

Comment: @Peter - try and see.  Hit F12 in your browser right now and paste my code into the JavaScript console.  You'll see that the properties are indeed shared.  This is the whole point of using `prototype`.  If everything were cloned, there'd be no difference from just defining everything in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks, I gotcha. We're just misunderstanding each other. The initial value/reference is shared yes. When I say clone, I meant a shallow copy, it's a new variable, but it's still pointing to the same `Date` object that was initially created when the property was first added to the prototype. My point is that subsequent setting of the property on an instance will not affect the others.

Comment: Your 'see also' pretty much answered what I wanted to know. Thanks.

Comment: @Peter - You are right that overwriting a prototyped property on an instance will not affect the others. But this is because a new property is created on the instance that hides the prototype's property. When you say `obj.foo`, `obj` is checked for a property named `foo`. If it is not found, the prototype chain is searched. `obj.hasOwnProperty("foo")` will return false when `foo` is only defined on the prototype. There is no shallow copy: Change the prototype of an existing object and then check the object for the change. If the values had been copied, no change would be seen on the instance.

Comment: Thanks for that info! I was not aware of that subtlety. It *does* make more sense. That pretty much answers my question. There is no point of putting something in the prototype unless it's going to be shared. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make "private" vars by adding them to the contrustor as var's instead of doing this.something; like so:

```
function MyObject()
{
    this.readableVar = "yes this is readable";
    var notReadable = "nope, not readable";  
};

var ob = new MyObject();
document.body.innerHTML = ob.readableVar + "<br />" + ob.notReadable;
```

These will not be shared and thus be specific to the instance you created with new.

One of the things to keep in mind when using prototypal inheritance is that every time you access a var thats not inside the instance but inside the prototype a lookup action is done throughout every step of the chain until a match is found or at the top of the chain undefined is returned.
This might become overhead when done repeatedly.

Hope it helps PM5544.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. However, I do want to go with the prototype approach. I just want to know if I should put *all* properties on the prototype, or only ones that are intended to be public. More of a best practice question when using the prototype.

Comment: These concepts can be used together, for instance you can make a constructor that has a prototype with all the shared public stuff and the private things in the instances.

But to try and answer your question:
Where you place your vars is all dependent on the data model, so it always a question of var accessibility, ease, maintainability and performance.
So i guess every situation is different and needs a different approach.
Maybe with some examples we could elaborate some...

Comment: Thanks. I know about the in between solution. Although it's not really that helpful since the methods on the prototype would have *no* way to access the private *closed over* instance variables. They would be unprivileged public methods. I honestly like the solution you suggest too. There is a slight memory overhead that we're trying to avoid which is why we're going with all prototype. To be honest, I'm not sure it's really worth it, because we could use more methods to partition scope as much as we want. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

I like the following pattern:

```
function Rectangle(x,y) {
  var _x = x,
      _y = y;
  this.area = function() {
    return _x * _y;
  }
}
```

_x and _y will be private and area() will be public.

Comment: Thanks, I really like that too! Although I'm asking about best practice when using the prototype. We want to use the prototype to minimize memory as much as possible.

Comment: Your examples are not equivalent. All the values of prototype properties will be shared by all instances (think about static values on a class). In the first case myInternalProp_ is a property of the instance (each instance will have their own value) and in the second case will be shared.

Comment: Yes that's true. In that case the constructor wasn't going to change the initial values, although in a more complicated example the constructor would set the new *instance* specific values. My question is more a consistency/best practice thing; essentially, why set only some on the prototype, why not let the engine know everything up-front since they will all be public anyway. I can still set instance values in the constructor if need be.