# Standard way to get a pre-calculated variable/property from a JS function's prototype

Tags: javascript, scope, prototype

I'm looking for the standard way to calculate a variable once, then access it within the scope of every execution of a function, without relying on global variables.

This seems like a standard use of prototype properties (variables) - but every example I can find on JS prototypes is based on prototype methods (functions). The only thing I can find about setting properties / variables in a prototype [is a question from someone who also couldn't find any information about these, asking if it's good or bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822838/using-prototype-for-variables) (tldr: it's fine, but remember it's rarely worth sacrificing readability for tiny performance gains).

I've got a way to set and get prototype properties that works, but feels clunky as it depends on a reference to the function (essentially `var prop = thisfunctionname.prototype.someprop`). Since I found it through trial and error, I'd like to ask if there's a cleaner, more standard way to get these prototype properties from within the function, without going back up to the scope around the function and getting the function from there?

---

Here's a simplified light-hearted example: an imaginary [jQuery plugin that adds a number to another number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif) then returns it in a sentence with the user's name. We want to ask the user their name only once, then store that name for re-use within scope:

```
(function($) {
  var sum = function( num1,num2 ) {
    var result = num1 + num2;

    // This works, but seems clunky since it depends on the variable `sum` 
    // from the scope around this function - is there a better way?
    var name = sum.prototype.name;

    $(this).text( num1+' plus '+num2+' is '+result+', '+name+'.');
    return $(this);
  };

  var name = prompt('Please enter your name','');

  // Is there a better way to set this default variable to be accessible 
  // in all calls to this function?
  sum.prototype.name = name;

  $.fn.basicArithmetic = sum;

})(jQuery); 
// end of plugin. Example usage...

$('<p/>').basicArithmetic(1,5).appendTo('body');
$('<p/>').basicArithmetic(2,2).appendTo('body');
$('<p/>').basicArithmetic(25,30).appendTo('body');
$('<p/>').basicArithmetic(92.3,15.17).appendTo('body');
```

[Live jsbin example.](http://jsbin.com/okumam/1/edit) More realistic real-life use cases would be when the calculation for the property is expensive in memory usage, or destructive (e.g. requires changing the DOM during calculation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different answers, really:

1. The usual way is to use a variable within a scoping function (you already have one handy in your example); no prototypes involved at all.

   ```
   (function($) {
     var name;

     name = prompt('Please enter your name','');

     function sum( num1,num2 ) {
       var result = num1 + num2;

       $(this).text( num1+' plus '+num2+' is '+result+', '+name+'.');
       return $(this);
     }

     $.fn.basicArithmetic = sum;

   })(jQuery);
   ```

   [Updated JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/okumam/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/okumam/2/edit)

   *(Side note: I also changed your anonymous function expression into a named function declaration, but it doesn't really matter in this case.)*
2. The usual way *in a jQuery plug-in* is to store the data on the element(s) the plug-in is being applied to. That doesn't work for the example you gave, which requires that the data be global to the plug-in, but normally (not always, just normally) plug-ins keep only instance-specific information, which you'd normally store on elements (probably via the `data` function).